# Adjust font size in UITextView on screen of different size

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView with some texts. I want the big screen has bigger font size but the format is same. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "big screen" ? bigger iPhone screen like iPhone 6 or 6 plus  comparing to the iPhone 5 ?

Answer (score 9):

I know it's a bit more advanced than the code-only solutions you've already found here, but I would encourage you to take some time and read about Adaptive Layouts: it's the future of UI development for different screens on iOS.

For instance, you can target different screen sizes and orientations using size classes. You can get an overview here: [width & height traits](http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/#width--height-traits).

Here are a few pointers if you need to begin from zero:

- [Apple - Adaptive User Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/)
- [Apple - Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)
- [Ray Wenderlich - Beginning Adaptive Layout Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)
- [Tuts+ - An Introduction to Adaptive Design](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-adaptive-design--cms-22888)
- [Adaptive Layouts for iPhone 6](http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/)

Answer (score 4):

You can detect the screen size of the device using `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height` and depending on the screen size you are you set a different font size.

See example below:

```
let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height

switch screenHeight {
case 480: // 3.5 inch
    UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)
case 568: // 4 inch
    UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)
default: // rest of screen sizes
    UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
}
```

Here you can check out the screen sizes [here](http://www.iphoneresolution.com)

Answer (score 1):

Here are all screen sizes :)

```
let screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width

switch screenWidth {
        case 320: // iPhone 4 and iPhone 5
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 16)
        case 375: // iPhone 6
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 18)
        case 414: // iPhone 6 Plus
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 20)
        case 768: // iPad
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 25)
        default: // iPad Pro
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 30)
        }
```